# Joining 2 MySQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql

I finally got all of my queries written (thanks to all who have helped me).

**The First One:**

```
SELECT 
  cards.card_id, 
  concat(cards.title, ' By Amy') AS TitleConcat, 
  cards.meta_description,
  cards.description, 
  '' as Bob,
  '' as Weight,
  '' as UPC,
  cards.seo_keywords,
  concat('http://www.amyadele.com/attachments//cards/',cards.card_id,'/',cards.card_image) AS ImageURL,
  card_import.artist,
  concat('ARTIST - ', card_import.artist) AS Brand,
  min(card_lookup_values.card_price) AS LowPrice,
 replace(lower(concat( 'http://www.amyadele.com/', pcat.seoname,'/',cat.seoname, '/', cards.seoname, '.htm' )),' ','+') AS link,
            concat(pcat.name,'>',cat.name) as Merchant


FROM
  cards
  join card_cheapest on cards.card_id = card_cheapest.card_id
  left join card_import on card_import.card_id = cards.card_id
  join card_lookup_values on card_lookup_values.card_id = cards.card_id
    INNER JOIN card_categories cc ON cards.card_id = cc.card_id AND cards.card_live = 'y' AND cards.active = 'y' AND cc.active = 'Y'
          INNER JOIN categories cat ON cat.category_id = cc.category_id AND cat.active = 'Y'
          INNER JOIN categories pcat ON cat.parent_category_id = pcat.category_id


WHERE card_lookup_values.card_price > 0
GROUP BY
  cards.card_id
ORDER BY
  cards.card_id
```

And **the Second One:**

```
SELECT cards.card_id, round(min(card_lookup_values.card_price), 2) AS 'price', min(cast(lookup_details.value as signed)) as 'quantity'
FROM cards
INNER JOIN card_lookup_values ON cards.card_id = card_lookup_values.card_id
INNER JOIN lookup_details ON card_lookup_values.lookup_detail_id = lookup_details.lookup_detail_id
WHERE card_lookup_values.lookup_id = 7
-- AND c.card_id = 'al007'
GROUP BY cards.card_id;
```

I tried a couple of times to get this to work **(my last attempt)**

```
SELECT 
  cards.card_id, 
  concat(cards.title, ' By Amy') AS TitleConcat, 
  cards.meta_description,
  cards.description, 
  '' as Bob,
  '' as Weight,
  '' as UPC,
  cards.seo_keywords,
  concat('http://www.amyadele.com/attachments//cards/',cards.card_id,'/',cards.card_image) AS ImageURL,
  card_import.artist,
  concat('ARTIST - ', card_import.artist) AS Brand,
  min(card_lookup_values.card_price) AS LowPrice,
 replace(lower(concat( 'http://www.amyadele.com/', pcat.seoname,'/',cat.seoname, '/', cards.seoname, '.htm' )),' ','+') AS link,
            concat(pcat.name,'>',cat.name) as Merchant,
 round(min(card_lookup_values.card_price), 2) AS 'price',
 min(cast(lookup_details.value as signed)) as 'quantity'

FROM
  cards
  join card_cheapest on cards.card_id = card_cheapest.card_id
  left join card_import on card_import.card_id = cards.card_id
  join card_lookup_values on card_lookup_values.card_id = cards.card_id
    INNER JOIN card_categories cc ON cards.card_id = cc.card_id AND cards.card_live = 'y' AND cards.active = 'y' AND cc.active = 'Y'
          INNER JOIN categories cat ON cat.category_id = cc.category_id AND cat.active = 'Y'
          INNER JOIN categories pcat ON cat.parent_category_id = pcat.category_id
INNER JOIN card_lookup_values ON cards.card_id = card_lookup_values.card_id
INNER JOIN lookup_details ON card_lookup_values.lookup_detail_id = lookup_details.lookup_detail_id

WHERE card_lookup_values.card_price > 0 and where card_lookup_values.lookup_id = 7
GROUP BY
  cards.card_id
ORDER BY
  cards.card_id
```

But I keep getting an error that says: **Not unique table/alias: 'card_lookup_values'**

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're joining twice to the `card_lookup_values` table. You must assign each reference to this table a unique alias to distinguish them. I've used `clv1` and `clv2` in the snippet below to illustrate.

```
...
join card_lookup_values clv1 on clv1.card_id = cards.card_id
INNER JOIN card_categories cc ON cards.card_id = cc.card_id AND cards.card_live = 'y' AND cards.active = 'y' AND cc.active = 'Y'
      INNER JOIN categories cat ON cat.category_id = cc.category_id AND cat.active = 'Y'
      INNER JOIN categories pcat ON cat.parent_category_id = pcat.category_id
INNER JOIN card_lookup_values clv2 ON cards.card_id = clv2.card_id
...
```

Comment: Oh. I presume I would also need too change my instances of card_lookup_values to either clv1? I did find that after making the change,I am getting the error Unknown table card_lookup_values

Comment: @Louis: Yes. Anywhere you're referencing a column from this table, you'll need to use the appropriate alias.